# filter enum in list of enums sqlalchemy

Tags: python, enums, sqlalchemy

I have the following enum in python:

```
class Status(enum.Enum):
    produced = 1
    consumed = 2
    success = 3
    failed = 4
```

and the following SQLAlchemy model

```
class Message(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    status = Column(Enum(Status))
```

I want to filter on several statuses in query like this:

```
session.query(Message).filter(Message.status in [Status.failed, Status.success])
```

But no matter what I have in my DB, the results are always empty, it's probably because don't understand the type of `Message.status`.

However, this does work:

```
session.query(Message).filter(Message.status == Status.failed or Message.status == Status.success)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use **[in_](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnOperators.in_)**  operator:

```
session.query(Message).filter(Message.status.in_((Status.failed, Status.success)))
```